# Link formation in a third-party .aspx website

Tags: asp.net, web

I want to understand what link is formed when I click print button on http://recruitment.cdacmohali.in/TETPB/Regprintagain.aspx

Sample data is 2011360220 and 25/05/1980

I want to integrate it with my website and get the url it it making so that in the url I can pass the registration number and dob as variable and see the complete results.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is using Session. You can not pass the data by QueryString